# For sitemaps, do I need to urlencode URLs with international characters?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, sitemap, url-encoding

We have urls that will contain international characters...

ex: `https://example.com/title/oh-wie-schön-ist-panama`

Do these special characters need to be URL encoded for the our sitemap for the crawlers?
`https://example.com/title/oh-wie-sch%C3%B6n-ist-panama`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest approach is to %-escape the special characters, according to this answer on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/533645/11985090